# php date conversion

Tags: php

How would i convert a format like:

```
13 hours and 4 mins ago
```

Into something i can use in php to further convert?

Comment: `strtotime()` seems to fail... The best way would not to have to parse natural language in the first place. Where is this coming from? No chance of getting a more machine-readable format?

Comment: it's to bad users can't go negative in their rep.

Comment: @Pekka so what? Doesn't 5 or even 2 questions deserve at least a sign of gratitude?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use strtotime(), and perhaps date() later, e.g.:

```
$thetime = strtotime('13 hours 4 minutes ago');
$thedate = date('Y-m-d', $thetime);
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
strtotime('13 hours 4 mins ago', time())
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 0):

To get a unix timestamp fromt he current server time:
`$timestamp = strtotime("-13 hours 4 minutes");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the DateInterval class - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php - which you can then sub() from a regular DateTime object.

Comment: DateInterval is nice, but I doubt it can parse the input string the OP is giving

Answer (score 0):

Do it the hard way:

```
$offset = (time() - ((60 * 60) * 13) + (4 * 60));
```

Working Example: http://codepad.org/25CJPL76

Explanation:

`(60 * 60)` is 1 hour, then `* 13` to make 13 hours, plus `(4 * 60)` for the 4 minutes, minus the current time.

What i usually do is create several constants to define the values of specific time values like so:

```
define("NOW",time());
define("ONE_MIN", 60);
define("ONE_HOUR",ONE_MIN * 60);
define("ONE_DAY", ONE_HOUR * 24);
define("ONE_YEAR",ONE_DAY * 365);
```

and then do something like:

```
$offset = (NOW - ((ONE_HOUR * 13) + (ONCE_MIN * 4)));
```

in regards to actually parsing the string, you should look at a javascript function and convert to PHP, the source is available from PHP.JS:

http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime:554

Comment: but this doesn't not parse the string

Comment: Updated. Updated with a possible solution.